# Editing margin box sizes in R pagedown package

Tags: css, r, pagedown

I want to reduce the margins on all sides of a pagedown document but I am having a hard time figuring out just how to accomplish this. I looked at the pagedJS documentation for the structure here: https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/07-generated-content-in-margin-boxes/

It says that the margin-boxes are sized according to the page area. So I thought I could change the dimensions here in  default-page.css

```
@page {
  size: 6in 9in; /* var(--pagedjs-width) doesn't work in browser when printing */
}
```

But the margin-boxes don't change and rather push the content off the page
[image]

Appreciate any advice on how to adjust the size properly!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following css:

```
:root {
--pagedjs-margin-right: 0.5in !important;
--pagedjs-margin-left: 0.5in !important;
}
```

The defaut width is 1in. Anything between 0 and 1 will lead to smaller margins.